# No Data Available with both side center (Verticla + Horizontal) with HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created data box for widgets in my project.

But i want my text to be in the center both Vertical and Horizontal  **without mentioning height for it**.

One more thing, I have `JS` Based solution for calculating heights. But i want pure `CSS` based solution.

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/3j7ydafw/5/

Comment: My Demo https://jsfiddle.net/3j7ydafw/5/

Comment: Your Demo seems to work fine with `CSS` itself even when I remove `height`?

Comment: Thanks Guru for quick Reply. Try with min-height:250px it wont work. the reason behind not using height is that after that content get out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this

```css
.content-contaner-right{
  background-color:#ddd;
  min-height:250px;
  position: relative
}

table{
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

td{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-contaner-right">                            
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td >textsdfsdf</td>
    </tr>
  </table>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. It Works ;-)